# Triangle over a word

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I couldn't find an example of below symbol.

Is there a symbol or package for this triangle?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package `yhmath` has such an accent as extensible math accent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \widetriangle{ABH},
  \widetriangle{\mathbf{ABH}},
  \widetriangle{\textsf{ABH}},
  \widetriangle{\textsf{\bfseries ABH}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]